# Moving a figure containing 4x5 images a bit right

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I have the following code to create a `4 x 5` figure but when I put this code in my document the resulting figure is always placed a bit too much to the right.

How can I move the figure a bit to the left?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\graphics}[1]{\includegraphics[width=4.cm]{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    mygrid/.style={matrix of nodes,
       row sep=-30\pgflinewidth, column sep=-30\pgflinewidth,
       nodes={minimum size=1cm}, nodes in empty cells},
]
\matrix (m) [mygrid]
{
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)},rotate=270]|10 droplets &\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-0.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-5.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-7.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-8.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-88_labeld.jpg}\\
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)},rotate=270]|50 droplets &\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-0.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-5.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-10.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-15.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-255_labeld.jpg}\\
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)},rotate=270]|100 droplets&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-0.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-15.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-30.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-45.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-600_labeld.jpg}\\
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)},rotate=270]|250 droplets &\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-0.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-30.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-60.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-75.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-950_labeld.jpg}\\
&  &  &  &  \\
};
\draw[thick,-latex] ([shift={(-2mm,-2mm)}]m-4-2.south west) --
         ([shift={(50mm,-2mm)}]m-4-5.south east)
               node[pos=0.5,below=10mm]{Time/minutes};
\draw[thick,-latex] ([shift={(-2mm,-2mm)}]m-4-2.south west) --
         ([shift={(-1mm,10mm)}]m-1-2.north west)
               node[pos=0.5,left=15mm,rotate=90,anchor=center]{Quantities};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please extend your code sniped to small complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and preamble with all relevant packages and definitions. welcome to the tex.se!

Comment: Welcome! We don't have your images. Do you still see the problem if you replace `par-dmso-sam1-250-0.jpg` etc. by `example-image-a`?

Comment: Yes I got the same problem

Comment: The main problem is that your tikzpicture is bigger than the text area (which is the same size in landscape, only rotated).  While it is centered left-right (which is up-down in landscape), it still starts at the top (which is the left side in landscape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to center the oversized tikzpicture (relative to the text area) by abusing a minipage.  I added the bounding box in green for demonstration purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\graphics}[1]{\includegraphics[width=4.cm]{#1}}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{minipage}[c][\textwidth][c]{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mygrid/.style={matrix of nodes,
       row sep=-30\pgflinewidth, column sep=-30\pgflinewidth,
       nodes={minimum size=1cm}, nodes in empty cells},
]
\matrix (m) [mygrid]
{
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)},rotate=270]|10 droplets &\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-0.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-5.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-7.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-8.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-10-88_labeld.jpg}\\
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)},rotate=270]|50 droplets &\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-0.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-5.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-10.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-15.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-50-255_labeld.jpg}\\
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)},rotate=270]|100 droplets&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-0.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-15.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-30.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-45.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-100-600_labeld.jpg}\\
|[shift={(-2mm,6mm)},rotate=270]|250 droplets &\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-0.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-30.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-60.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-75.jpg}&\graphics{par-dmso-sam1-250-950_labeld.jpg}\\
&  &  &  &  \\
};
\draw[thick,-latex] ([shift={(-2mm,-2mm)}]m-4-2.south west) --
         ([shift={(50mm,-2mm)}]m-4-5.south east)
               node[pos=0.5,below=10mm]{Time/minutes};
\draw[thick,-latex] ([shift={(-2mm,-2mm)}]m-4-2.south west) --
         ([shift={(-1mm,10mm)}]m-1-2.north west)
               node[pos=0.5,left=15mm,rotate=90,anchor=center]{Quantities};

\draw[green] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% just for show

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that op is forgot on his question ... anyway,  one more answer:

- as basis i took [John Komylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo) answer
- instead of `landscape` i use `sidewaystable`; by this is use of `minipage` superfluous
- increase text area (with help of package `geometry). if this is not desired then you have twoo possibilities to fit image in text area:

  1. localy increas text area (for example with use of `changepage` packet)
  2. reduce size of images
- reduce matrix size (remove empty row)
- draw coordinate axis regarding to matrix edges
- define style for the first column and with this simplify code for cells in it.
- add package `graphicx` with option `demo` that enable to see demo images
- reduce the size of images (from 40mm to 35mm) but this should be increased again in use of real image (it they have different aspect ratio
- for defined new command for inserting images in matrix i select new name because for it use name which is already used in `latext` is not reasonable

*mwe*:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\img}[1]{\includegraphics[width=35mm]{#1}}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mygrid/.style={matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-1\pgflinewidth, column sep=-1\pgflinewidth,
        inner sep=1mm,
        nodes={inner sep=1pt},
        nodes in empty cells},
        column 1/.style = {nodes={rotate=270,anchor=east,xshift=-7mm}}
]
\matrix (m) [mygrid]
{
10 droplets
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-10-0.jpg} & \img{par-dmso-sam1-10-5.jpg}
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-10-7.jpg} & \img{par-dmso-sam1-10-8.jpg}
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-10-88_labeld.jpg}\\
50 droplets
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-50-0.jpg}  & \img{par-dmso-sam1-50-5.jpg}
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-50-10.jpg} & \img{par-dmso-sam1-50-15.jpg}
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-50-255_labeld.jpg}\\
100 droplets
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-100-0.jpg} & \img{par-dmso-sam1-100-15.jpg}
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-100-30.jpg}& \img{par-dmso-sam1-100-45.jpg}
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-100-600_labeld.jpg}\\
250 droplets
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-250-0.jpg} & \img{par-dmso-sam1-250-30.jpg}
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-250-60.jpg}& \img{par-dmso-sam1-250-75.jpg}
    & \img{par-dmso-sam1-250-950_labeld.jpg}\\
};
\draw[thick,-latex] (m.south west)
        -- node[below] {Time/minutes} (m.south east);
\draw[thick,-latex] (m.south west)
        -- node[sloped,above] {Quantities} (m.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

[image]